# Why can I have a dichotomous predictor in linear regression but not a dichotomous outcome

Tags: regression, logistic, correlation

For linear regression, it is possible to have both continuous and dichotomous predictors. I assume this might have a similar rationale as the point-biseral correlation, where we have one dichotomous and one continuous variable.

I was wondering, however, why it doesn't work the other way round; why can't a linear regression be used to predict a dichotomous outcome from a continuous variable?

I am sure there is a logical explanation and I'd be curious to know more about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question, then the answer is: "We can try to use a linear regression to predict a dichotomous variable...but should we?"

Your question basically gets to the heart of Generalized Linear Models. I won't cover that in detail here because it's discussed on the site extensively. I'll just add a brief, hopefully intuitive way to think about it.

A simple linear regression takes the form:

$$y_i = \beta x_i + \epsilon_i, \text{ with }\epsilon_i \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$$

Now imagine each $x_i$ is a positive, continuous number taking on large values (say square footage of a house), and each $y_i$ takes on values $1$ or $0$ (sold or not sold). You want to find the $\beta$ that fits this model the best using a linear regression.

The problem is that the quantity $\beta x_i$ is unbounded. So you might have estimates that are much greater than 1 or much smaller than 0. Say after performing maximum likelihood estimation, you get $\beta$ = 4.5. Say $x_1 = 1000$. What does it mean for $\hat{y_1} = 4500$? Do we assign that a value of $1$? Do we have more evidence for this house being sold than we do for a house with $\hat{y_2} = 2500$? How do we interpret $\beta$ in this case? You can certainly do this, and perhaps have a custom threshold such as:

$$
 y_i = 
  \begin{cases} 
   1 & \text{if } \beta x \geq 1000 \\
   0       & \text{if } \beta x < 1000
  \end{cases}
$$

But again, you lose something in the way of interpretability. As an aside, you get a function that isn't differentiable everywhere (because of the kinks at the extremes) which could make certain learning tasks tricky.

What we want instead is to encode this type of threshold *apriori* in the model, not after the fact like above. That is, we want a way to map values of $\beta x$ that are large to be close to 1 and values that are small to be close to 0. When I say large and small, I'm talking arbitrarily large or small.

To do this, you need to apply some transformation function ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model#Link_function)) to our linear predictor, $\beta x$. This relates to [Generalized Linear Models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model), of which there is a lot of information on this site.

Usually for dichotomous outcomes we might use a logit link, yielding the [logistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model#Binary_data) regression. You've probably seen the [sigmoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) function before.

Instead of solving for $y_i$ (some potentially large or negative number) we solve for $p_i = P(y_i=1|x_i)$ - a probability that is between 0 and 1, reflecting what we want out of our dichotomous outcome.

The problem then becomes:

$$P(y_i=1|x_i) = p_i = \frac{1}{1+e^{-\beta x_i}}$$

Where we define:

$$\text{logit}(p_i) = \text{log}\big(\frac{p_i}{1-p_i}\big) = \beta x_i$$

So you see that we are reframing the question in terms of a probability instead of actual value. This is how we bound the output to be between 0 and 1, aligning with our intuition that a house can either be sold or not sold.

Note that you can reinterpret this to be a latent variable model, similar to the thresholding above:

$$
 y_i = 
  \begin{cases} 
   1 & \text{if } \beta x + \epsilon \geq 0 \\
   0       & \text{if } \beta x + \epsilon < 0
  \end{cases}
$$

Where $\epsilon$ follows a Logistic distribution. When $\epsilon$ follows a Normal distribution, we get a [probit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probit_model) regression. To show this, you simply solve the formula for $\epsilon$ and use it's CDF to find the probability. The [Logistic Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_distribution) has a CDF that's effectively the same (given the right parameters) as our definition for $p_i$.

In general these transformations ensure that our outcomes will always be between 1 and 0, because of how they are defined. There are a number of beneficial properties that fall out of that, including the interpretability of the coefficients in this case, and statements such as "The probability of a house of size 1000 square feet getting sold is X%", something a linear regression can't give you. And now you can more easily compare houses against each other, with respect to their propensity to be sold.

**Edit**

I figured that a visual might help deliver the message. `scikit-learn` has an [example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_logistic.html) that illustrates what we're talking about above. I present it below, in full, slightly modified to include this notion of a threshold:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn import linear_model

# this is our test set, it's just a straight line with some
# Gaussian noise
xmin, xmax = -5, 5
n_samples = 100
np.random.seed(0)
X = np.random.normal(size=n_samples)
y = (X > 0).astype(np.float)
X[X > 0] *= 4
X += .3 * np.random.normal(size=n_samples)

X = X[:, np.newaxis]
# run the classifier
clf = linear_model.LogisticRegression(C=1e5)
clf.fit(X, y)

# and plot the result
plt.figure(1, figsize=(10, 8))
plt.clf()
plt.scatter(X.ravel(), y, color='black', zorder=20, marker='x')
X_test = np.linspace(-5, 10, 300)


def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

loss = sigmoid(X_test * clf.coef_ + clf.intercept_).ravel()
plt.plot(X_test, loss, color='red', linewidth=2)

ols = linear_model.LinearRegression()
ols.fit(X, y)


def threshold(x):
    if ols.coef_ * x + ols.intercept_ >= 1:
        return 1
    elif ols.coef_ * x + ols.intercept_ <= 0:
        return 0
    return ols.coef_ * x + ols.intercept_

lin_pred = [threshold(i) for i in X_test]

plt.plot(X_test, lin_pred, linewidth=2)
plt.axhline(.5, color='.5')

plt.ylabel('y')
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.xticks(range(-5, 10))
plt.yticks([0, 0.5, 1])
plt.ylim(-.25, 1.25)
plt.xlim(-4, 10)
plt.legend(('Logistic Regression Model', 'Linear Regression with threshold'),
           loc="lower right", fontsize=14)
plt.title("Logistics Regression compared to Linear Regression\n for dichotomous outcome", size=16)
plt.show()
```

[image]

And finally, we can make predictions using both models - although only probabilistic statements with Logistic Regression. Hopefully it's readily obvious why Logistic Regression would be preferred to Linear Regression:

```
x = 3
print("When x=3...")
print("Linear Regression predicts:", threshold(x)[0])
print("Logistic Regression predicts:", int(clf.predict(x)[0]))
print()
x = 10
print("When x=10...")
print("Linear Regression predicts:", threshold(x))
print("Logistic Regression predicts:", int(clf.predict(x)[0]))

# When x=3...
# Linear Regression predicts: 0.757941284936912
# Logistic Regression predicts: 1

# When x=10...
# Linear Regression predicts: 1
# Logistic Regression predicts: 1

print("Probability that class = 1 when x = 0.2:", clf.predict_proba(0.2)[0][1])
print("Probability that class = 1 when x = 1.5:", clf.predict_proba(2.5)[0][1])

# Probability that class = 1 when x = 0.2: 0.4335699991588034
# Probability that class = 1 when x = 1.5: 0.9998355617824308
```